# Why do my earlier epochs take longer than subsequent epochs?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am training a model in `keras`, and experimenting with how the amount of data I feed in affects my resulting accuracy. I noticed something interesting though.

```
training samples: 5076
epoch 1: 142s
epoch 2: 60s
epoch 3: 61s
epoch 4: 60s
epoch 5: 61s

training samples: 10242
epoch 1: 277s
epoch 2: 131s
epoch 3: 131s
epoch 4: 132s
epoch 5: 131s

training samples: 15678
epoch 1: 385s
epoch 2: 323s
epoch 3: 167s
epoch 4: 168s
epoch 5: 168s

training samples: 20691
epoch 1: 577s
epoch 2: 440s
epoch 3: 273s
epoch 4: 274s
epoch 5: 274s
```

My intuition is that each epoch should take roughly the same amount of time.

I notice with smaller training sets, the first epoch takes longer than subsequent ones. I assumed that this was because I have written my own data loader and that there was some amount of 'spinning up' happening during the first epoch. But with larger training sets, I notice that the second epoch is taking longer than subsequent epochs too.

Why do the earlier epochs take longer? Are more weights being updated in those earlier runs?

Comment: What is the platform you are using for your training ? and could you add the snippet of code that is responsible for running the epochs.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most intuitive reason I could think of for early epochs taking more than than latter ones, is that for your early epochs, your classification/regression system's error is very high at the beginning (which is a natural thing given random weights), thus there are plenty of gradients to back-propagate and many weights to update.

It could be that your model is fitting the training data too quickly (in approx 2 epochs), that the latter epochs are only updating  a smaller percentage of the weights, since most of the gradients are now 0. This could lead to a lesser training time per epoch.

Try and output either the average accuracy or even better the gradients matrix for each epoch, and check for the above assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The extra time in first epoch can be due to compilation overhead for building parts of computational graph for training.

About the second epoch, it's a bit tricky. I assume it can be something to do with your optimizer's way of upgrading gradients. for example, I have seen people mentioning that increasing `beta_1` value from `0.9` to `0.99` for an `adam` optimizer, sometimes reduces epoch duration.

Also, if your model is fitting quickly to the data, that would mean less updates and hence faster execution. But that seems unlikely for your case as you seem to encounter the problem only when increasing the training sample size.

Answer (score 1):

Although both answers have merit, I believe they miss an important part, the reliance on the amount of data.

Keras caches data to be able to use it again later. Hence, there is a significant boost in training after the first epoch. I am not exactly sure, but I assume that with larger amounts of data, it does not originally cache all the data.

Based on a similar [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/51231/very-fast-training-after-first-epoch).